# VBA Excel loop for copying multiple tables with string change

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Good morning,

I would like to develop a loop, which will give me the possibility to copy and paste a multitude of tables depending on the cell value.

[image]

As you can see, I put value 3 and the 3 tables have been populated (min is number one, which means that 1 table always remains). The string with number also have been changed accordingly.

Everything would be alright, but this process is manual. I need it as a loop.
What I developed so far is the loop, which doesn't work properly. I am getting all copies only for the cell "B43". I need these copies populated all the way down every 13 steps. If range of 2nd column starts from B43, the range of another one should start from "B56", "B69","B82", etc.

```
 Sub CopyCabinet()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range
 Dim wr As Worksheet

 Set wr = Sheets("NIM & BADGER")

 Set rg = wr.Range("R27")
 Set rg2 = wr.Range("B30:W41")
 Set rg3 = wr.Range("C31")


 For i = 1 To rg Step 2
 With rg3
 .Value = "Level 4 Cabinet Details: Cabinet " & i + 1
 End With

 rg2.Copy _
    Destination:=wr.Range("D43")
 Next I

 End Sub
```

The string also doesn't change properly.

Is there any way to fix it?
I found some reasonable hint here:
[Copying and pasting loop in VBA Excel for multiple outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068514/copying-and-pasting-loop-in-vba-excel-for-multiple-outputs)
which means that I must set new range, where I redirect my input. I that correct?

Comment: Don't hardcode your destination, use an offset based on `i` - each time you want to go 13 rows down (or whatever it is).

Comment: how can I plot offset into my code then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is a bit of here. What if you change a value and then copy/paste old values back over it? Nothing happens for the eye really. Also, what happens if you copy `B30:W41` and paste it to column D? It will get wonky.

So say you want to copy the specific range at hand x amount of times, you could rewrite your code to something like:

```
Sub CopyCabinet()

Dim i As Long
Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range
Dim wr As Worksheet

Set wr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NIM & BADGER")

With wr
    Set rg = .Range("R27")
    Set rg2 = .Range("B30:W41")
    Set rg3 = .Range("C31")

    For i = 1 To rg.Value - 1
        rg2.Copy .Range("B30").Offset(13 * i)
        .rg3.Offset(13 * i).Value = "Level 4 Cabinet Details: Cabinet " & i + 1
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

You should still recognize the structure you were going for, however I think I streamlined it a bit more for you here. Obviously I can't test this so report back if this has worked for you or if there is any hickups here.